# Optimize Arrives at Wrong Answer when Interval Increased

Tags: r, optimization

Does anyone know what's going on with the optimize function here? I'm trying to find the minimum sample size given that I want to do a 90/10 control/test split to achieve power of 80.

```
library(pwr)

# Proportions

p1 <- .09*1.2
p2 <- .09

Cohen.h = ES.h(p1, p2)

getNRatio <- function(n, p=.8){

  n1 <- n * .9
  n2 <- n * .1

  power <- pwr.2p2n.test(h = Cohen.h, n1 = n1, n2 = n2, sig.level = .05, power = NULL, alternative='greater')$power
  return((p - power)^2)
}

> optimize(getNRatio, interval=c(0, 1e6), maximum=FALSE, p=.8)
$minimum
[1] 1e+06

$objective
[1] 0.04


> optimize(getNRatio, interval=c(0, 1e5), maximum=FALSE, p=.8)
$minimum
[1] 18875.37

$objective
[1] 6.907866e-20
```

Why does optimize find the right answer when I set the interval to have a lower bound and fail with a higher bound??

Comment: The documentation of optimize says that there is no guarantee to converge to a global minimum, maybe (0,1e6) is an unlucky interval.  The `optimize()` function is designed for continuous functions, but `pwr.2p2n.test` seems to be expecting integer inputs for n1 and n2, I'm not sure what it returns for non integers

Answer (score 0):

So I think this just has to do with the method using gradient descent. A plot of the entire interval generates this:

[image]

So if we used a naive binary search method and started in the middle, then the gradient at that point would be flat and provide no help towards finding the minimum. However with a smaller interval, the first guess might actually have a useful gradient that points toward the global minimum.